# How do you override sectionIndexTitlesForTableView using core data?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm would like to create a table that displays the date in full for the section headers, eg. @"EEEE dd MMMM yyyy". Then in the the fast user index on the righthand side use the @"MMM" value to provide quick access to a given month.

I can get the index to work using the default value of first character from the core data. So the fetchedResultsController is working and pulling in the right data. I've checked the documentation for any suggestions to override this method. It says it can be done but stops short of showing how it's done.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation page for the [UITableViewDatasource](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) has the method you are looking for.
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't help. I think the problem is with my use of FetchResultsController. The documentation suggests overriding the sectionIndexTitles instance method but it doesn't suggest how to alter the default criteria for this method. Currently the method in this class provides the first character of the section head to be used for the index. I want to recalculate the subString with the first three characters after the second space. For example if the section head is, Wednesday 30 December 2009 the index should be Dec. Perhaps there is an easier way?